# How to use some lodash method to check if one property doesnt match within two arrays using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have 2 array of objects like so,

```
const initial = [
    {
        id: '1',
        value: '1',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        value: '2',
    }
]

const current = [
    {
        id: '1',
        value: '3',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        value: '2',
    },
]
```

these two arrays are almost the same.

i want to check if the current array has value different than the initial array with same id.

so if atleast one of the object in current has value different from the initial value then it should return true. if not false.

so in above example current array with id 1 has value 3 which is different from initial value with id '1'.

i was trying to do something like below,

```
const output = current.filter(item => some(initial, {id: item.id, value: !item.value}))
```

but this doesnt seem to be the right way. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Does the position in the array matter ? is the `id` guaranteed to be unique in each array ?

Comment: position meaning the object properties might be in different level? seems like not

Comment: position meaning, if the object with `id:1` is the first object in both arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), save the id-value pairs of `initial`
- Using [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), iterate over `current` to compare

```js
const _isDifferent = (initial = [], current = []) => {
  const map = new Map( initial.map(({ id, value }) => ([id, value])) );
  return current.some(({ id, value }) => map.get(id) !== value);
}

const 
  initial = [ { id: '1', value: '1' }, { id: '2', value: '2' } ],
  current = [ { id: '1', value: '3' }, { id: '2', value: '2' } ];
console.log( _isDifferent(initial, current) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code,we can compare the length to find if it has different value

```
let checkDiffArray = (arr1,arr2) => 
   arr1.filter(a1 => arr2.some(a2 => a2.id === a1.id && a2.value === a1.id)).length != arr2.length
```

```js
const initial = [
    {
        id: '1',
        value: '1',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        value: '2',
    }
]

const current = [
    {
        id: '1',
        value: '3',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        value: '2',
    },
]

let checkDiffArray = (arr1,arr2) => arr1.filter(a1 => arr2.some(a2 => a2.id === a1.id && a2.value === a1.id)).length != arr2.length

console.log(checkDiffArray(initial,current))
```

Comment: thanks what the last part .length != arr2.length does

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`differenceWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceWith) combined with the [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual)

```js
const initial = [
    { id: '1', value: '1' },
    { id: '2', value: '2' }
]

const current = [
    { id: '1',value: '3' },
    { id: '2',value: '2' },
]

const output = Boolean(_.differenceWith(current, initial, _.isEqual).length);
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: this is giving the object but how do i get the boolean value out of it

Comment: @natalia Just wrap a `Boolean` around its length. `const output = Boolean(_.differenceWith(current, initial, _.isEqual).length);`